# Symfony validation get specific error by property

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I know how to validate and how I can retrieve the error messages.
But how can I get a specific error entry by property?

NOT like this:

```
{% for error in errors %}
    <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I mean something like this:

```
getError($errors, 'myProperty');
```

Is something like this possible?

> I use the validator, but not the form class. I got
>   \Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationListInterfac‌​e - with
>   an array of all error messages.

I am sadly not in Twig context ... I need it for smarty .. I want to show directly a error message for a specific field like this:

```
    <label for="city">{getError($errors, 'myProperty')}</label> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
      <input class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City *" type="text">
    </div>
```

Comment: I assume this is `Form` component related, right? :)

Comment: no sadly not ... :-/

Comment: Alright, so `errors` varibale originates from `Validator`?

Comment: yes I use the validator, but not the form class. I got \Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationListInterface - with an array of all error messages.

Answer (score 1):

### `Validator`-based idea:

So, if you have access to your `Validator` class, you ***might*** be able to do something like this:

```
$validator->atPath('myField')->getViolations();
```

which would return `ConstraintViolationListInterfac‌e`, but due to `atPath` call, it should return only a subset of violations.

Must say, I have never tried it myself, but it sure sounds like it could work.

### `Form`-based solution, not very useful to you

`Form` class has the method `getErrors()` method:

```
 public function getErrors($deep = false, $flatten = true)
```

In your example, you could call:

```
 form.myField.getErrors()
```

Or via variable:

```
 {% set varWithFormName = "myField" %}

 form[varWithFormName].getErrors()
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: hm okay thanks. Problem is here - I am not in the form class - is there another method to retrieve error message for a specific field without the form class?

Comment: Since you said that you do not use `Form` component, this is useless to you :)

Comment: yes ... with normal form class I think this could work. But not for my specific case.

Comment: Added a `Validator` based solution, but first check out @Matteo's solution. It looks interesting given that you usually have a small number of errors...

Answer (score 1):

Try if this code works for you:

```
{% for error in errors %}
   {% if error.propertyPath == 'myProperty'  %}
      <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can create a [TWIG macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) that accept the errors and the field that handle the render.

Let me know

Comment: I am sadly not in Twig context ...
I need it for smarty .. I want to show directly a error message for a specific field like this: 
<label for="city">{getError($errors, 'myProperty')}</label> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
      <input class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City *" type="text">
    </div>

Comment: Hi @goldlife i don't know smarty but i think you can find a system to incapsulate the logic into a function or something of reusable, obviously: if my code works for you :)